# How can I detect with AngularJS if the app is offline?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have many customers in remote areas and lost of connectivity is frequent. How can I detect if the javascript app is offline? Meaning cannot reach the server and load the templates.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242389/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-angularjs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a JSFiddle that does exactly that: Check if the web application is online. It uses `window.navigator.onLine`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rommsen/QY8w2/

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/ZncvSVUc9y4/S4jH1e_XgGoJ

Comment: Note that `windows.navigator.onLine` has different implementations depending on the browser, and a status of `true` only indicates connection to a LAN or router, not to a specific resource or the broader internet. You may need to specifically test connection to your desired resource and check for 404 to properly test offline conditions.

Comment: You may want to check out [Offline.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline), an open-source library built for just this purpose.

Comment: I didn't D/L it, I just opened up their simulator. rather than using their checkbox to pretend, I actually pulled my Ethernet cable.  In Chrome & MS IE, I go the "you are offline" alert. FF did not show it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242389/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-angularjs   which indicates that FF seems to be non-standard

Comment: I just checked the Plunk in the awarded answer : works with Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137 m, MS IE v11.0.x.x, but NOT with FireFox v29.0.1

Comment: This fiddle seems not working. Note that the rootScope cannot be injected in factory.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.online = $window.navigator.onLine;

$window.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    $scope.online = false;
});

$window.addEventListener("online", function() {
    $scope.online = true;
});
```