# How to check internet connection in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

This is how I would check internet connection in vanilla javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(navigator.onLine){
        $("body").html("Connected.");
    }else{
        $("body").html("Not connected.");
    }
},1000);
```

I have angular controllers and modules in my project. Where should I put the  code above? It should be executed in global context and not be assigned to a certain controller. Are there some kind of global controllers maybe?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574580/how-can-i-detect-with-angularjs-if-the-app-is-offline

Answer (score 153, accepted):

First of all, I advise you to listen to [online/offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events).

You can do it this way in AnguarJS:

```
var app = module('yourApp', []);

app.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
      $window.addEventListener("offline", function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = false;
        });
      }, false);

      $window.addEventListener("online", function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = true;
        });
      }, false);
});
```

NOTE: I am wrapping changing of root scope's variable in `$apply` method to notify Angular that something was changed.

After that you can:

In controlller:

```
$scope.$watch('online', function(newStatus) { ... });
```

In HTML markup:

```
 <div ng-show="online">You're online</div>
 <div ng-hide="online">You're offline</div>
```

Here is a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3LkiI7Cj4RWBNRLEJUA?p=preview

Other solution could be to broadcast online/offline event. But in this case you need to initialize current status upon loading and then subscribe to event.

Comment: Your js code has a typo, you are missing a ')' to close $apply(. Just tried it and I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of undefined

Comment: Note this doesn't work in FireFox. They have chosen to implement navigator.onLine differently from every other browser, which is really hurting developers that want to develop offline apps.

Comment: Strange - from the article that I've referenced: "Firefox 3 introduces two new events: "online" and "offline"." So it should work.

Comment: @waqas check this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: Works with Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137 m,  MS IE v11.0.x.x, but NOT with FireFox v29.0.1

Comment: Not working on chrome. I opened plunker and i show `online:true` then I turned off my wifi and it still shows `online:true`.

Comment: Doesn't fire on android devices

Comment: **A word of warning: This only checks if your computer is connected to a network and not if you are actually online.**

Comment: seams to be deprecated, from given link I found: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#offline

Comment: use `emit && broadcast` instead of `$window.addEventListener`

Answer (score 19):

It's definitely not as nice, but you could just try an AJAX request to your web server; it'll either succeed or time out.

Also, the [HubSpot/offline project](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline) looks really good.

Comment: !+ but, Lol: that's what I am trying to replace. I had a service which is responsible for attempting to reconnect. Anyone who tries an `$http.get` and gets 404 can invoke the service which would 1) broadcast that there was no internet (so that no one else would try to connect), 2) regularly attempt to connect to my server and, 3) when successful, stop the connection attempts and broadcast that the app is now online again.  However, that seemed very klunky and this solution seemed elegant - except for FF :-(  I cannot be reinventing the wheel here. How do others do it?

Comment: Oops, see my comment to the the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574580/how-can-i-detect-with-angularjs-if-the-app-is-offline    "I didn't D/L it, I just opened up their simulator. rather than using their checkbox to pretend, I actually pulled my Ethernet cable. In Chrome & MS IE, I go the "you are offline" alert. FF did not show it. See also stackoverflow.com/questions/16242389/… which indicates that FF seems to be non-standard"

Answer (score 1):

Your options:

- addEventListener on the window, document, or document.body.
- setting the .ononline or .onoffline properties on document or
  document.body to a JavaScript Function object.
- specifying ononline="..." or onoffline="..." attributes on the tag in
  the HTML markup

I will demonstrate the easiest.

In you controller

```
document.body.onoffline = function() {
   alert('You are offline now');
   $scope.connection = 'offline' 
}

document.body.ononline = function() {
   alert('You are online again');
   $scope.connection = 'online' 
}
```

Check $scope.connection variable before you try to send requests around.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 2+ you can use [ng-speed-test](https://github.com/jrquick17/ng-speed-test):

1. Just install:

```
npm install ng-speed-test --save
```

2. Inject into your module:

```
import { SpeedTestModule } from 'ng-speed-test';

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [
       SpeedTestModule,
       ...
   ],
   ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3. Use service to get speed:

```
import {SpeedTestService} from 'ng-speed-test';

@Injectable()
export class TechCheckService {
  constructor(
    private speedTestService:SpeedTestService
  ) {
    this.speedTestService.getMbps().subscribe(
      (speed) => {
        console.log('Your speed is ' + speed);
      }
    );
  }
}
```