# Angular is giving up to load view, after Internet Disconnection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have ng-route:

```
.when('/home', { 
    templateUrl: "/view/pages/home.html",
    controller: "homeController",
    controllerAs: 'home',
    caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
    resolve: myResolve
})
```

After I disconnect the internet, to simulate network issues, angular is throwing an error:
*Failed to load template: /view/pages/home.html*

And after I connect internet again, angular is not trying to reload view.
How can I tell angular, to keep trying to load view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet connection in AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242389/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Angular will fire on page load.  If the internet connection goes away, and then is reconnected on the same page.  The application will not try and reload the page.  The user would then have to try to navigate to a new page or new resource.  This would cause the application to load again.

Not to mention that the application is run in the browser, but in order to load the controller into the user's browser.  The user must have an internet connection.

Comment: The OP gets that, they are trying to know how to tell angular to load it again once the internet connects again...

Comment: I believe this answer from stack exchange is what you are looking for.                                                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242389/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-angularjs

Comment: Well I now know online and offline events. But still don't know how to tell angular, to not load view, until user won't be online.