# I want to display an alert message status if I lose an internet connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS, how can I display an alert message status if I lose an internet connection in my app?

I am working on Angularjs Express framework and APIs.
while working on app if I lose internet connection I need to pop up an alert and I should stop calling HTTP requests until I receive a proper internet connection and resume the work.

I even tried with offline.js am not able to solve please if any simple and easy method is there let me know thank you. In header I added all these

```
<script src="/javascripts/plugins/offlinechecking/offline.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/themes/offline-theme-chrome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/themes/offline-language-english.css" />
<script>
  Offline.options = {
    checkOnLoad: false,
    interceptRequests: true,
    reconnect: {
      initialDelay: 3,
      delay: (1.5 * last delay, capped at 1 hour)
    },
    requests: true,
    game: false
</script>
```

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242389/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

You can use online and offline events:

```
app.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
      $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = false;
        });
      }, false);
      $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = true;
        });
      }, false);
});
```

More info: [How to check internet connection in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242389/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-angularjs)

Moreover, you didn't close your `Offline.options` object:

```
Offline.options = {
// No closing }.
```

Comment: Can you add the interval task for your answer?

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo Sure will do.

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

- addEventListener on the window, document, or document.body.
- setting the .ononline or .onoffline properties on document or
  document.body to a JavaScript Function object.
- specifying ononline="..." or onoffline="..." attributes on the
   tag in the HTML markup

I will demonstrate the easiest.

In you controller

```
document.body.onoffline = function() {
   alert('You are offline now');
   $scope.connection = 'offline' 
}

document.body.ononline = function() {
   alert('You are online again');
   $scope.connection = 'online' 
}
```

Check `$scope.connection` variable before you try to send requests around.

---

**Update for Comment1**

If you need the variable to be global, set it in a factory

```
myApp.factory('connectionStatus', function(){
   var connection;

   return connection;
})
```

Now inject this factory wherever you need to use it. This is how it goes inside your main controller where you set the events.

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, connectionStatus) {
    document.body.onoffline = function() {
           alert('You are offline now');
           connectionStatus = 'offline' 
    }
})
```

Comment: hi, if i what to check `$scope.connection` variables i have 13 controllers. in each file i have to check  i want this should be in global

Comment: Updated based on your comment