# How can check offline and online in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I have been getting an error from the service call when browse is in offline mode. How can check off-line mode and want to block my service call when the browser is the offline mode?

Comment: this I Know my Question is how can  block my service call

Comment: add an http interceptor, that before each call, do this check.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use [Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)

they have templates and other stuff to work with .
you can check out their [documentation](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/) and see how it works .

it gets you the current state of the connection by returning the "up" or "down" result , or you can bind and event to it and use it across you'r application .

this is what they say about their library :

> Offline.js is a library to automatically alert your users when they've lost internet connectivity, like Gmail.
>
> It captures AJAX requests which were made while the connection was down, and remakes them when it's back up, so your app reacts perfectly.
>
> It has a number of beautiful themes and requires no configuration.

good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 4):

Check for `navigator.onLine`and based on this value decide whether to send request or not.

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
    $http.get('url').success(function() {});
}
else {
    // no req
}
```

Angular way:

Use `$q` service - A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

The best way that I would know would be to intercept the HTTP handler, if its a 401 / 501/ etc. then to handle it according

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services'], 
    function ($httpProvider) {

    var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function ($rootScope, $q) {

        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {
            var status = response.status; // error code

            if ((status >= 400) && (status < 500)) {
                $rootScope.broadcast("AuthError", status);
                return;
            }

            if ( (status >= 500) && (status < 600) ) {
                $rootScope.broadcast("ServerError", status);
                return;
            }

            // otherwise
            return $q.reject(response);

        }

        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        }

    }];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

then in your code that listens for the on of, just add in

```
$rootScope.$on("ServerError", someServerErrorFunction);
```

Source: [How to detect when online/offline status changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851424/how-to-detect-when-online-offline-status-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Online/offline detection cannot be 100% accurately decided because network status can vary for a number of reasons.

Still, if you want an implementation of the same with Angular+NGRX, You can find more details here.

https://hackernoon.com/using-angular-to-detect-network-connection-status-onlineoffline

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

import { fromEvent, merge, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  networkStatus: boolean = false;
  networkStatus$: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.checkNetworkStatus();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.networkStatus$.unsubscribe();
  }

  checkNetworkStatus() {
    this.networkStatus = navigator.onLine;
    this.networkStatus$ = merge(
      of(null),
      fromEvent(window, 'online'),
      fromEvent(window, 'offline')
    )
      .pipe(map(() => navigator.onLine))
      .subscribe(status => {
        console.log('status', status);
        this.networkStatus = status;
      });
  }
}
```

[You can see the demo here](https://angular-check-offline-online.stackblitz.io/?ref=hackernoon.com).

[or check the code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-check-offline-online?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&ref=hackernoon.com)

Happy coding!!!